# /dev/nvme0n1p2 clean stuck loading

Tags: boot, grub2

The last thing I did was add"acpi_backlight=vendor" to

GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor
And then I got a login loop so I tried to troubleshoot with [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop) thread, and now I am stuck on a black screen that says /dev/nvme0n1p2: clean with some file and block numbers, it has been this way for an hour. I tried holding shift on boot and I could not boot in safe mode.

I have a asus vivobook 15
I am using Ubuntu 20.04.01

Comment: Ah sorry Ubuntu 20.04.01